# Android - Facebook Analytics - Push campaign setup verification not working

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, facebook-analytics

I implemented FB Push Campaigns in our Android app. However I seem to be not able to run the "Push campaign setup verification".

[image]

I have a few questions that I am unable to find an answer for:

1. Where does the "YOUR DEVICE TOKEN" come from? What device are we
   talking about in this context.
2. The status is saying:

> The sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated.
>   This is probably due to an invalid project number being sent as the
>   key, or the key could be valid but with the GCM service disabled, or
>   our servers have not been whitelisted in the server key IPs.

[According to this article](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/968699896561804)

[image]

the problem is that "GCM sender ID is invalid". I verified our GCM and it is correct. I am quite confused about what is actually wrong or how to properly work out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide [GCM server key](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key) in Facebook settings for push notifications

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the
>   Firebase Console using the Cloud Messaging tab of the Settings panel.
>   Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported
>   in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/) without affecting their existing
>   configuration.

Device token is the registration token of your device which is generated when you first install your app after FCM/ GCM integration.

Comment: Indeed this was our case. Thanks @random :)